# Header file not found sometimes using Cocoapods HockeySDK

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I have a build script using the  `xcodebuild` command line tool using the `archive` action.

- The build **succeeds**:

  - on my machine using xcode.
  - on my machine using the build script.
  - on the build server using xcode.
- The build **fails**:

  - on the build server the build script.

The failure is related to a missing header in one of the pods. (It happens to be the HockeySDK).

```
=== BUILD TARGET Pods-HockeySDK OF PROJECT Pods ===
....
CompileC ... /Library/TeamCity/../Pods/HockeySDK/Classes/BITCrashReportTextFormatter.m:34:9: 
fatal error: 
  'CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h' file not found
```

The line is:

```
#import <CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h>
```

In file, ([source is here](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/blob/develop/Classes/BITCrashReportTextFormatter.m))

```
/../MyApp/Pods/HockeySDK/Classes/BITCrashReportTextFormatter.m
```

The actual header can be found in the framework here:

```
/../MyApp/Pods/HockeySDK/Vendor/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CrashReporter.h
```

I have noticed there are 2 links to the file in the XCode project navigator, not sure if this is a clue or not:

[image: Pods]

So I assume it is a missing header search path?  However, I have ran a pod install and pushed the changes to the build server.

We are using using HockeySKD - 3.5.4 (the latest).  [The podspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4giHl.png) has a link to the crash reporter framework using this syntax (not sure how it works).

```
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Vendor/CrashReporter.framework'
```

The search paths in the pods project looks like this:

[image: search paths in the pods project]

Answer (score 2):

The build is failing because of the pod header files got corrupted because of the TeamCity git checkout.

To fix change the checkout mode from Automatically on Server to Automatically on agent (need to select show advanced) and enable clean on checkout for one build.

Comment: Having the same problem. How did you end up solving it exactly? Did you recreate your Pods project?

Comment: Yea essentially just nuked the repo and re-cloned it - ill add the script I added to detect the error and recover from it.

Comment: This hasn't fixed it for me.  I think there's a problem with Hockey's pod as has been discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin - I think when I had this problem it was actually effecting every pod.  IRC this was fixed by changing the teamCity checkout rules from automatically on server to automatically on agent and doing a clean checkout.

Comment: @Robert  That worked!  Thank you, I spent the whole of yesterday on that problem.

Comment: @DanyalAytekin - you mean the teamCity settings?  ... I might change my answer to reflect this

Comment: Yes - (1) changed VCS checkout mode to 'Automatically on agent', (2) added configuration parameter `teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, but I couldn't resolve it by choosing my checkout to "Automatically On Agent" because my repo had way too many projects. I needed sub projects within this project, so I have to rely on checking out "Automatically on Server".

The problem with the cocoapods is that the symbolic links are broken when you check them out form git on teamcity. I added a new build step to fix that as follows:

```
rm /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Headers
rm /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/HockeySDK
rm /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Resources

ln -s Versions/Current/Headers /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Headers
ln -s Versions/Current/HockeySDK /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/HockeySDK
ln -s Versions/A/Resources /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Resources

rm /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/Current
ln -s A /Git/YourCheckoutDir/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/Current
```

[image: Build Step Setup]